# AWS CDK: How to reference custom Docker image from public ECR repository

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-codebuild, amazon-ecr

I've successfully tested out a manual CodePipeline/CodeBuild test action to run Cypress UI tests with the public Docker image `public.ecr.aws/cypress-io/cypress/browsers:node16.17.0-chrome106`

Now on trying to codify the setup into CDK, I can't find a complete code example on how to reference the custom image. The docs only offers a very terse block that doesn't explain where the (public) ECR repository comes from.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/dotnet/api/Amazon.CDK.AWS.CodeBuild.html

```
Environment = new BuildEnvironment {
    BuildImage = LinuxBuildImage.FromEcrRepository(ecrRepository, "v1.0")
}
```

Checking out the AWS.ECR namespace doesn't explain how to reference public repositories with the static methods either.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/dotnet/api/Amazon.CDK.AWS.ECR.Repository.html#methods

How is the CodeBuild project's BuildEnvironment object supposed to be coded to properly use that public custom image?

Comment: BuildImage =  LinuxBuildImage.FromDockerRegistry("public.ecr.aws/docker/library/node:16-bullseye-slim")

Comment: Thanks @VikramS you should put that up as answer. Since the doc states it pulls image from Docker Hub, I'd never have guess it can reference ECR as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BuildImage = LinuxBuildImage.FromDockerRegistry("public.ecr.aws/docker/library/node:16-bullseye-slim")

Comment: Thank you. Since the doc states it pulls image from Docker Hub, I'd never have guess it can reference ECR as well.